# Kendo Autocomplete: datasource update dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have a working autocomplete text box fetching data from mysql server through a php file.

I would like to know how to change the datasource i.e the table depending on the user selection dynamically.
Can the autocomplete requery a new table?

I am using the following tutorial
http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-10-02/using_the_autocomplete_with_php.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the server sending an extra parameter:

1. using [`transport.parameterMap`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportparametermap-function))
2. using [`transport.read.data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportreaddata-objectstringfunction)

or you can do it in the client (browser) defining:

1. [`transport.read`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportread-objectstringfunction) as a function that load the data (likely via ajax).
2. [`transport.read.url`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#transportreadurl-stringfunction) function that calculates the URL of one or the other service.

Comment: oh, yeah. The parameter map. Thanks a lot!